# Scapy: Sending Raw Ethernet Frame doesn't show up in Wireshark

Tags: python, python-3.x, networking, network-programming, scapy

I want to send a simple packet to my Ethernet Interface: "enp0s31f6". I have tried sending a L3 IP packet using my wifi card and it works fine, but using the L2 function and sending a raw Eth frame is showing "Sent 1 packet" but not showing up in Wireshark.

I have a very simple script.

```
from scapy.all import *

g = Ether(dst=get_if_hwaddr("enp0s31f6"))
sendp(g, iface="enp0s31f6")
```

The output shows:

```
.
Sent 1 packets.
```

However, viewing Wireshark on the enps031f6 channel, I'm not seeing any packets being sent, at all. Same with tcpdump. Any idea?
I have confirmed that the get_if_hwaddr gives me the correct MAC address for the interface I'm using.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on linux and using the default `L2socket`, it hides by default all outgoing packets (and sadly there's currently no way of turning that off).

You can workaround this by using libpcap sockets instead, by adding:

```
from scapy.config import conf
conf.use_pcap = True
```

somewhere in your code

Comment: The purpose of me using sendp, specifying the interface is so I could send the packet out of the ethernet interface, to the ethernet interface. I don't want anything to do with wi-fi. I just tried sending an L2 packet using ```Ether()/IP()``` and I'm not seeing anything on my wifi card nor my ethernet card.

Comment: Instead of sending an empty packet, I tried sending a packet containing a string converted to bytes: ```sendp("Test", iface="enp0s31f6")``` but it's still not sending anything to or from the ```enp0s31f6``` interface.

Comment: My ultimate goal is to "virtualize" the sending of the ethernet packet. I don't have anything hooked up to my ethernet interface, but I want to virtualize the sending of this packet from my eth interface, to itself. Then, when I hook another machine up to it, I can just change the dest MAC addr.

Comment: I think I understood your issue wrongly, I changed my answer. Could you check that?